# Azure Notification Hub: Does SendTemplateNotificationAsync work for .net Core

Tags: azure, push-notification, notifications, .net-core

I am using preview version of the Azure Notification Hub in .Net Core project. On our server, I have it install the device for the notification hub. I can managed to install the device to notification hub in the backend, and able to do a test send to iOS devices through the portal.

I tried to add a line in my backend code

```
[HttpPost]
    [Route("TestMessage")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> NotifyByTemplate([FromBody] ApiAttendanceModel model)
    {
        //string jsonMessage, IDictionary<string, string> additionalProperperties, string tagExpressions
        var additionalProperties = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        additionalProperties.Add(Constants.Constant.NotificationMsgName, "asdf");
        var hub = NotificationHubClient.CreateClientFromConnectionString(Constants.Constant.NotificationConnectionString, Constants.Constant.NotificationHubName);
        var result = hub.SendAppleNativeNotificationAsync("{'aps':{ 'alert':'Notification hub test notification' }}");//await hub.SendTemplateNotificationAsync(additionalProperties);

        return Ok(true);
    }
```

I even used hub.SendTemplateNotificationAsync. There is no notification coming in.

I wonder the preview version work pushing the notification is working for .net Core yet.

Answer (score 0):

I wee that you are not awaiting to **hub.SendAppleNativeNotificationAsync**.
It may cause the problem that your method returns before the Notification sent and you loose the context.